# Bind TextBox Controls From Autocomplete TextBox Using ASP.Net core mvc Visual Studio 2017

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-ajax, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-1.1

I'm working on a asp.net core 1.1 project using EF Core.

Starting from a text inserted in a Textbox on my `Create.cshtml` page (where I use autocomplete function) I want to bind other textbox controls fetching data from my entity framework database and populating other textboxes with their values.

On my `Create.cshtml` ViewPage I have 2 fields: `CityOfBirth` and `ProvinceOfBirth`.

For the sake of simplicity I write the code only for the `CityOfBirth`.
On my `Create.cshtml` I have:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="CityOfBirth" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="CityOfBirth" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" id="searchCityOfBirth"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="CityOfBirth" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

For both textboxes I have implemented the autocomplete functionality both in the `Controller`:

```
public JsonResult AutocompleteCityOfBirth(string term)
    {

        var cityOfBirth = (from cOB in _listaCIcontext.Listacomuniitaliani.Where(x=>x.Comune.StartsWith(term))
                         select new
                         { value = cOB.Comune, label = cOB.Comune }).ToList();


        return Json(cityOfBirth);

    }
```

and also in the `site.js` file

```
$(function () {
$("#searchCityOfBirth").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Criminals/AutocompleteCityOfBirth",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { term: request.term },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return { label: item.term, value: item.value }
                }));
            },
        });
    },
    delay: 0,
    messages: {
        noResults: "",
        results: function (resultsCount) { }
        //results: ""
       },
    });
 });
```

The autocomplete function is working well.
What I'm trying to do now is to populate the other textbox (in my case `ProvinceOfBirth`) based on the value I've inserted in the textbox `CityOfBirth`retrieving the data from my database.

Of course, also starting from `ProvinceOfBirth` and getting filled `CityOfBirth` should be possible.

For this reason I've written in my `Controller` the following method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult FillTextBoxes(string fetch)
    {
        var query = (from c in _listaCIcontext.Listacomuniitaliani
                    where c.Comune == fetch
                    select c).ToList();

        return Json(query);
    }
```

The `string fetch` contains the autocomplete-textbox string, that I want to use to retrieve the other value from the database.
The `query` List (in `json` format) contains the queried database values.
How should I use them now to populate the `ProvinceOfBirth` textbox?

Comment: The step by step link below  worked for me like a charm: http://learningprogramming.net/net/asp-net-core-mvc/autocomplete-in-asp-net-core-mvc-and-entity-framework-core/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working.

To do that, I've slightly modified my controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetProvinceOfBirth(string fetch)
    {
        var query = (from c in _listaCIcontext.Listacomuniitaliani
                    where c.Comune == fetch
                    select c.Provincia).ToList();

        return Json(query);
    }
```

querying down to the `provincia` property.

Additionally, and this is the core of the solution, I've used the `.on('focusout')` method like that:

```
$("#searchCityOfBirth").on('focusout', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Criminals/GetProvinceOfBirth",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { fetch: $("#searchCityOfBirth").val()},
        success: function (query) {
            $("#searchProvinceOfBirth").val(query[0]);               
        },
    });      
});
```

For sure I will add some error handling to complete the code .... and invest more time for my knowledge in jQuery & AJAX

Answer (score 1):

What you can do here is: if autocomplete has any event that raises when you select an item, or you can just make `onchange` event on that input, and then you should send a get request to controller with ajax. Then in success you just take the data and just go and assign like `$('#provinceOfBirth').val(data.province)`. p.s. you get that `data` object from ajax response `success: function(data)`

Comment: Hi Ertan, I've added the following code `$("#searchCityOfBirth").on('change', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Criminals/GetProvinceOfBirth",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#searchProvinceOfBirth").val(data.value);
            },
        });      
    });` but the change event does not fire when I enter text in the textbox. When I cancel the text it fires. That is pretty strange.

Comment: @Code4Fun `change` function fires after you lose focus of that element, to make it fire when you start typing you should you `input` or `keyup`. They're almost the same, you can search and you will find which will fit you better.

Comment: Hi Ertan, thanks a lot. I will give it a try. In the meanwhile I've solved my problem using `focusout`. In my case the event must fire after that I've entered completely the text.

Answer (score 0):

Change to:
url: "http://" + window.location.hostname + "/Your_Application_Name" + "/Criminals/GetProvinceOfBirth",